# DJANGO API REST FRAMEWORK: schema methods

Tags: django, list, rest, api, frameworks

Django 1.11.3, python 3.6

I have 2 classes in my view.py:

```
class ProductList(generics.ListAPIView):

class SampleList(generics.ListAPIView):
```

Please note the same superclass. Might be relevant: Product is an actual model, Sample is not, `SampleList` is just a method that calls `Product.objects.all()` (same code as in `ProductList`)

All the code inside those classes besides class names is IDENTICAL (including serializer) - I just copied the class and renamed the copy).

The client before it hits urls for those two gets the schema

```
    schema = self.client.get(self.myAppApiUrl)

    #works, returns the results
    result1 = self.client.action(schema, ["products", "list"])

    params = {"id" : some_id, }

    #fails with this: coreapi.exceptions.LinkLookupError: Index ['samples']['list'] did not reference a link. Key 'list' was not found.
    result2 = self.client.action(schema, ["samples", "list"], params)
```

When I print "`schema`", I see

```
   products: {
        list([page])
    }
    samples: {
        read(id)
    }
```

1. My questions are: what makes it to add `"list"` to `schema` in the first case and `"read"` in the second case? And how can I add "list" to the second case? Maybe some schema update needs to be done somehow? The API web server was restarted.
2. What does that message `"Key 'list' was not found"` mean? Does this failure have something to do with the `params` passed? Removing `params` from the client call does not change anything.
3. I am also somewhat curious about what is that "`page`" thing in `list` and what adds that and but that's not important.

Comment: You say `Sample` is not a model, and you say `SampleList` is basically a list of `Product`. Why do you expect your schema to be able to list 'samples'? Not sure where your read(id) comes from but probably you do have a `Sample` model with a `RetrieveAPIView` somewhere?

Comment: @dirkgroten `SampleList` is supposed to produce a custom product list, so the first step is to get product list the same way `ProductList` does it anyway, then tweak it. I started from that and got that "Key 'list' was not found" surprise.

Comment: But that shouldn’t be a surprise since there is no ‘list’ view on a ‘samples’ model.

Comment: @dirkgroten . OK, if it's expected, how can I execute a hit to the view from my client for that  class method? I can not do it with `'list'` option since `'list'` is not an option, only `'read'`. When I try `'read'` I get `"coreapi.exceptions.NoCodecAvailable: Unsupported media in Content-Type header 'text/html"` which suggests that's the wrong thing to do. Maybe there is a way to implement `list` for that class without creating a model?

Comment: You'll probably have to manually specify the schema for that view: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/schemas/#per-view-schema-customisation, and create a URL pattern for your view. Note that `page` means you can pass a `page` query parameter to the api call in order to request a specific page in the list. But if your view is only different in that it filters the `products`, why not add that as a filter parameter to the first view?

Comment: @dirkgroten I thought just to add another filter parameter.. In reality it does not invoke just filtering on one of the model's fields, applying that filter requires connections to several other models which makes it a "non-exisitng model" view anyway. So I decided on a separate class and that did not fly. As of the schemas link you provided - I'll try those suggestions now, thanks, I already do some manual_fields, did not quite get yet how to add custom "actions", like 'list'...

Comment: Start by just adding your own url pattern for the view. I guess you auto-generate your schema (you haven't told us how the schema is created)? It should detect the pattern you add.